# Compress Oracle Query Column

Tags: sql, oracle, compression

I have read access to an Oracle database. I am using cx_Oracle to make queries. One of the table column is a CLOB with XML strings. To speed up the network access I figured I would try to ask the database to first compress the xml data before it sends it because the network link is very slow. Is there any way to do this? I would uncompress the data on my end. Looking for something like:

```
SELECT COMPRESS(clob_column) AS comp_data
FROM table1
WHERE id=1
```

Thanks

Comment: How big is the data?  Look here - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_compr.htm#ARPLS70838

Comment: Rather than storing the XML as a CLOB you should store it as binary XMLType which by definition is already compressed. XMLType also gives you advantages if you ever have to query the XML itself . Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/ADXDB/choice-of-XMLType-storage-and-indexing.htm#ADXDB6348

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have permissions to change the database in any way. I am just trying to make queries with SELECT.

Comment: Trying to use UTL_COMPRESS.LZ_COMPRESS doesn't seem to work. It gives me argument type error. I wonder if it only works with BLOB's and not CLOB's? 

Does the function work with queries using SELECT?

Comment: Do you guys think if I did this it would compress it before it sends?

SELECT XMLTYPE(clob_column) FROM table1 where ID=1

Comment: Also I should first ask if anyone knows if the database communication protocol compresses big CLOB data first before it sends it? If so then my question is mute since everything should be done for me already and nothing is left to improve. 

Thanks